# jQuery - Slide down div

Tags: jquery

I have a table cell and what I want is that if the user clicks on the table cell a div collapses (div is in another table cell).

`$(function slideDown(id) {
    $("getdiv"+id).fadeIn();
});`

The table row (hover function):

`<tr class="odd" id="div96" onhover="slideDown(96)"><td>ZZZn  ZZZ</td></tr>`

The table cell (needs to fade in/slide down):

`<tr><td id="getdiv95" class="divinside" style="display: none;">Text</td></tr>`

I'm sorry for my poor English.

[Demonstration image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1yl0.png)

Comment: First, it's not clear what your question is. Second, did you mean to include function invocation () after slideDown?

Answer (score 1):

You are doubling up the 'div' part.

```
var name = $(this).attr('id');
$("#" + name).slideDown();
```

The way you have it written now it would look like

```
$("#divdiv1")...
```

Instead of

```
$("#div1")...
```

Also, wrap all this in a $(document).ready(function(){}); so that it triggers the click binding after all the tr elements have loaded.

Comment: My code now is:
 $(function() {
    $('.odd').click(function(e) { 
 var name = $(this).attr('id');
 $("#" + name).slideDown();
 });
});
But it won't work..

Comment: Is it possible to create a function that I can use like <td onClick="showUser(41)">, where div41 is the id of the div I want to slide down?

Comment: Try wrapping the function in $(document).ready(function(){});

Answer (score 0):

Slide down is a function, you must invoke it in order for it to be run:

```
$("#div" + name).slideDown();
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. Is it possible to create a function that I can use like <td onClick="showUser(41)">, where 41 is the id of the div I want to slide down.

Comment: IDs shouldn't start with a number (unless you are using html5 in which case I think this may be allowed).  You should add the html of your `div` into the question.  I think there may be some confusion there.